# How can i put all map keys in to a list?

Tags: dart, flutter

usually i would  use a for , but how can i do to search the entire map key and put in to a list.

```
List<String> test= new List<String>();


Map<String, bool> values = {
    'foo': true,
    'bar': false,
    'bar2': false,
    'bar3': false,
    'bar4': false,
    'ba2r2': false,
    'ba2r': false,
    'ba3r': false,
    'b4ar': false,
    'b1ar': false,
    'b1a3r': false,
    '2b1ar': false,
    'b12ar': false,
    'b1a1r': false,
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
var keyList = values.keys.toList();
```

- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Map/keys.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html